# Inverse linear model doesn't seem exact inverse

Tags: r, linear-model

I'm dealing with a quantity that diminishes over time from 100% to 0%.  I'm trying to plot the values, a lm abline, and large indicative points where the graph intersects `y==100%` and `y==0%`.  I'm finding the results of `lm(y~x)` don't appear to be the inverse of `lm(x~y)` and I'm confused why this should be for a deterministic calculation.  This illustrates in `R`:

```
set.seed(100)
d = data.frame(t = sort(sample(1:60,10)), q = sort(sample(1:100,10), dec=T))

# linear model - dependant y
fit = lm(q ~ t, d)

# predicting x where y == c(100,0) - i.e. dependant x
pred = predict.lm(lm(t ~ q, d), data.frame(q=c(100,0)), se.fit=T)$fit
pred = data.frame(t = pred, q = c(100,0))

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,100))
axis(1); axis(2)
points(d)
abline(fit)
points(pred, pch=16, cex=2, col='red')
```

Why don't the red points not fall on the line?  I know the modelling/plotting here is probably topsy-turvy, but I'm interested in the principal..

[image]

Comment: you're right I think it is.  I think I get why now.  Still, that page could be a bit easier to find..

Comment: Agree, it took me few queries to find this thread even while knowing that it is somewhere there. But the community is one of the mechanisms behind this site ;)